# Is there a way to split string by "any character"?

Tags: c#

I need to make a program that splits strings by any characters + specified characters.
For example, I have a string like this " 1. word 2. otherword 3. anotherword" and I need to get only the words (split = {"word", "otherword", "anotherword"})

Is there a way to type something instead of * that would split the words regardless of what character may be between specified characters?

```
string[] split = content.Split(new string[] { " *. " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: so do you want to split on any character other than a letter?

Comment: What if one of the words is `don't`? Or `self-imposed`?

Comment: You can use [`Regex.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-7.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Split_System_String_) to split by anything that is not `a-z` and then remove the empty results. There may be some special characters that are allowed in words

Comment: Might need to tweak the regex in the duplicate answer a bit (e.g. use a dot (`\.` ) instead of a colon.

Comment: Another approach could be splitting by whitespace and then postprocessing the results to remove anything before the first and after the last letter

Comment: Something like `Regex.Split(str, @"(\d+\.\s)")`